# Grunt.js; Understanding different configs

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs

I'm really new to Grunt.js, and have had some luck being able to run some of the tasks I've installed (e.g. `watch`, `uglify`, `jslint`). As I try to run more, I often run into issues and try to google/research as much as I can in order to learn from the ground up how Grunt works.

However, I get confused by different configurations like these two for `uglify`:

From the GitHub Repo for [grunt-contrib-uglify](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify)

```
uglify: {
  my_target: {
    files: {
       'dest/output.min.js': ['src/input1.js', 'src/input2.js']
    }
  }
}
```

and this one (which works for me in my `Gruntfile.js`):

```
uglify: {
    build: {
        src: 'js/custom-script.js',
        dest: 'js/custom-script.min.js'
    }
},
```

It's not really these in particular, but I notice that each uses its own words (`my-target` versus `build`, `src`, `dest`), structure, syntax, etc. I think that, since Grunt is all javascript, that these would be all in `JSON` formats, though I wasn't able to verify if they were or not.

After doing lots of research through the Grunt documentation, going through the GitHub repositories containing the plugins, and random various tutorials, I guess I have some main questions:

- Is there a standardized way to write a `Gruntfile.js`?
- Are there any reserved words for `Gruntfile.js`'s? I have tried changing in my `uglify` task the word `dest` to `gibberish`, and it did fail, so my gut on this say yes.
- If yes to any of the above two questions, where are these resources/links? I tried to google `"grunt glossary"` but came up empty. The only standard seems to be the one that Grunt itself supplies, but I'm having a hard time getting things to work by referencing only it.

Comment: Not really and nope to your two questions. There is a ["format" to config each task](http://gruntjs.com/getting-started#the-gruntfile), but that's not really a standard (at least outside of the JavaScript language it uses), more something that is decided by each plugin. I may be misunderstanding the question.

Comment: Ah I see. So each format/set of keywords is decided by the writer of the plugin? I may change my question to be more specific to "formats for task configuration".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple things at work here, and not all config are created equal. The reference doc is http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks but here's a summary:

- most grunt tasks are what is called ["multi-targets"](http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#task-configuration-and-targets), meaning in your build process you might call the task multiple task, with different parameters. In the config, your first level is the name of the target, and it is completely free (except for `options`, see below). In your examples, these are the `build` and `my_target` names.
- besides these targets, you may have an `options` field (reserved keyword) that is passed to all targets
- in the targets themselves, grunt provides some reserved keywords, for options (`options`) and to define files (`src`, `dest`, `files`,... see http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#files)
- and the task author is free to define its own keys, so the doc of each task is very important.

Comment: Thank you! Reading your comments makes reading the reference make much more sense.